# Changing Content of Window from Button Click in User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am working on a program that has a main window with only a `ContentControl` element.
 In the class for this main window, I can change the content by `ContentHolder.Content = new UserControlMain()`. In `UserControlMain`, I have a button to once again change the content of the window to a new user control.

I am running into issues with changing the window content the second time. If I do not instantiate a class of `MainWindow`, I cannot access the `Content` property from anywhere except its own class. I also cannot access the `ContentControl` element I have associated with that class. However, if I do instantiate a `MainWindow` object, I run into an error message stating that the content has already been set.

Any tips on how I may get around this?

Comment: Can you post some code? I also ran into same problem. I was able to make it work by using MEFedMVVM framework. BTW you can expose the ContentControl by using a simple trick. Give the ContentControl in the xaml a name x:Name="_contentControl" and then in the code behind use a public Property "public ContentControl ContentContainer { get { return _contentControl; } }"

Comment: What about binding the content of the contentcontrol to some property , and change what you need in this property.

Comment: @user2760623 I did that by using the MEFedMVVM. In that framework there is a a NavigationHelper. Here is the [link]http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2011/08/27/mefedmvvm-navigationextension/. Then I do this to target the ContentControl from a button NavigationExtensions.NavigationHost="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=ContentContainer}

Comment: @aks81 I actually got around the issue by using Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new UserControlMain() since I am only using one MainWindow in my application. If I run into issues again doing it this way, I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is:

In MainWindow create a Grid with a name

```
<Grid name = "mainGrid">

</Grid>
```

Then, in code behind you can do easily this:

```
mainGrid.Children.Clear();
mainGrid.Children.Add(new UserControlMain());
```

Regards,